# Access string from firstviewcontroller in fourthviewcontroller objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

Hi can I access a string from `firstviewcontroller` in `fourthviewcontroller`. I used following code. But when I go to the `fourthviewcontroller` string is null.

```
firstviewcontroller.m
#import "Fourthviewcontroller.h"

Fourthviewcontroller view = [[Fourthviewcontroller alloc] init];
view.devInText = devInput.text; //devInput is a UItextfield
NSLog(@"%@",view.devInText); // output is correct 

fourthviewcontroller.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *devInText;

fourthviewcontroller.m
NSLog(@"%@",_devInText); // output displays null
```

Comment: You are alloc and initialize your view so that's why it is always null

Comment: Do one one thing  Compare , NSLog(@"%@", view) and self  (in fourthviewcontroller.h) and let me know what is difference

Comment: You are navigating from firstviewcontroller to fourthviewcontroller ??

Comment: Show more code, How you are navigating from firstviewcontroller to fourthviewcontroller?

Comment: Best way is use singleton design pattern http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two approaches:

1. Make the string Global variable  and set it from VC1 and later on
   access it from VC4 (not preferred).
2. While instantiating destination VC pass value for variable
        from VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4, in this way you can get the required
       data in VC4.